# Can I enable tracing in OWIN?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, owin, trace

I have an environmental problem somewhere in OWIN and I want to get some information about what is happening. I have read that I can enable tracing but can't find much information on how to do it.

I have added the following to my web.config but no joy. Is this possible?

```
<!-- 1. Enable the switch here. Without this, you get nothing. By default, Katana has "new SourceSwitch("Microsoft.Owin")" at the root level. -->
<switches>
  <add name="Microsoft.Owin" value="Verbose" />
</switches>

<!-- 2. Add your shared listeners. -->
<trace autoflush="true" />
<sharedListeners>
  <add name="file" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="C:\traces\Microsoft.OWIN.trace.log" />
  <add name="console" type="System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener" />
</sharedListeners>

<sources>
  <!-- "Microsoft.Owin" is the SourceSwitch name katana is using at the rootlevel. By enabling this, we are enabling all sub level traces by the components (if we don't change the default trace settings). -->
  <source name="Microsoft.Owin">
    <listeners>
      <add name="file" />
      <add name="console" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
```

Comment: Same problem here, I've added the configuration as per http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/logging-in-the-owin-world-with-microsoft-owin--introduction for example, hosting the OWIN app in IIS/Katana, but no trace file ever gets created. It parses the configuration, uses it in the logger factory, has rights to write to specified location, but still doesn't seem to work

Comment: Can you please share you Startup class? and provide more detail in your question. What are you going to trace(Requests?, Errors?) Do you use any middleware in Owin Pipeline?

Comment: Well, my problem is now solved. Somehow we lost the reference to Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb assembly. The NuGet package was installed, but the reference gone. The result of this is that everything runs absolutely OK, except the fact that the custom Startup class never gets detected and executed, so only the default OWIN configuration (and in our case WebAPI hosting) is used. Reinstalling the NuGet package solved it. I have no idea if that is the case for the @Jamie, but I encourage you to reinstall the package hell.

Answer (score 6):

Not 100% sure that this will solve your issue, but we got it working with following config.  Slight difference in the following line:

```
<source name="Microsoft.Owin" switchName="Microsoft.Owin" switchType="System.Diagnostics.SourceSwitch">
```

Notice that the `<source>` tag includes a `switchName` (and `switchType`) attribute which is missing from your example.  I think that this instruction links the TraceSource with the Switch and makes the entire work.

In our case, we use trace listeners for Azure Web sites (and web jobs).

```
 <system.diagnostics>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="AzureTableTraceListener" type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.WebSites.Diagnostics.AzureTableTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.WebSites.Diagnostics, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <add name="AzureBlobTraceListener" type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.WebSites.Diagnostics.AzureBlobTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.WebSites.Diagnostics, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <add name="AzureDriveTraceListener" type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.WebSites.Diagnostics.AzureDriveTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.WebSites.Diagnostics, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </sharedListeners>
    <sources>
      <source name="Microsoft.Owin" switchName="Microsoft.Owin" switchType="System.Diagnostics.SourceSwitch">
        <listeners>
          <add name="AzureTableTraceListener"/>
          <add name="AzureDriveTraceListener"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <switches>
      <add name="Microsoft.Owin" value="All" />
    </switches>
    <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4" />
  </system.diagnostics>
```