# ASP.NET Identity Change Password Validation False Negative

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am using ASP.NET MVC + Entity Framework and Identity

I am tearing my hair out because about 10% of my users are experiencing an issue on changing password.  I am using mostly stock code from the project generation. The only change is the user redirect depending on role following sign in on success

Most users have a seamless experience changing the password, but for about 10% of them, when they click submit it gives them an error that the password is incorrect.

It turns out that it has actually updated the password, but because of the error message, they continue to try use the original password. I cannot replicate it on my dev machine to debug, but I have seen it in practice at my clients

Can anyone see any issue with the code or experienced this before ?

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator, ...")]
    public ActionResult ChangePassword()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [Authorize(Roles="Administrator", ...)]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ChangePassword(ChangePasswordViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }
        var result = await UserManager.ChangePasswordAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), model.OldPassword, model.NewPassword);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
            if (user != null)
            {
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: true, rememberBrowser: false);
            }

            if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard", new      Area="Admin"});
            }

                // if all else fails redirect the user back to the default web site.
            return Redirect("http://www.example.com");
        }
        AddErrors(result);
        return View(model);
    }
```

EDIT - Following comment below here are the models. They are autogenerated boilerplate code:

```
public class ChangePasswordViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Current password")]
    public string OldPassword { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "New password")]
    public string NewPassword { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm new password")]
    [Compare("NewPassword", ErrorMessage = "The new password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Users and Passwords are set in code:

```
String password = "password";
String username = "user1";
var user = new ApplicationUser
{
        UserName = username,
        Email = "useremail.com",
};
var result = UserManager.Create(user, password);
if (result == IdentityResult.Success)
{
    UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Admin");
}
```

Comment: I have a few suggestions to find the root cause: 1) Add some logging to the code. In ChangePasswordAsync and ChangePassword methods, in each if statement, log a different message. Make sure your logs have the user ID, so next time someone faces the issue, you can trace the events in the log for the specific user. Also, check to see if you are caching the credentials on the server. If so, then the issue could be that your cache is out of sync with the new data

Comment: Show code for `ChangePasswordViewModel` and code for model where user creates password in the first place. I suspect that in one place special chars like `<` are allowed in password, but not allowed in the other one.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably more suited as a comment but the formatting would drive me nuts so I am going to put it here. The following should enable extra logging in the OWIN pipeline.

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <switches>
    <add name="Microsoft.Owin" value="Verbose" />
  </switches>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Also if that does not show enough or does not work for you, check out the following post where it adds a lot more stuff to it: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30086820/3850012)