# No log file created by Microsoft.OWIN

Tags: logging, owin, system.diagnostics

I am experiencing an intermittent problem between my application, Identity Server, and the Microsoft.OWIN layer. The issue is probably something I am doing wrong, but may actually be a bug in Microsoft.OWIN. In order to better understand the root cause of the problem, I am trying to turn on logging in the OWIN layer.

I followed [this post by Tugberk Ugurlu](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/logging-in-the-owin-world-with-microsoft-owin--introduction), but nothing ever gets written to the log file.

Here is my web.config file entry.

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <switches>
        <add name="Microsoft.Owin" value="4" />
    </switches>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
    <sharedListeners>
        <add name="file" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="OWINtrace.log" />
    </sharedListeners>
    <sources>
        <source name="Microsoft.Owin" switchName="Microsoft.Owin" switchType="System.Diagnostics.SourceSwitch">
            <listeners>
                <add name="file" />
            </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>
</system.diagnostics>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this? I'm also struggling to get some log data from my Owin app. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The answer to this post might work for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28546227/can-i-enable-tracing-in-owin